# Getting SSE instruction set version supported by CPU using windows batch program

Tags: windows

How to get which SSE (SSE3/SSE4.1/SSE4.2) is supporting by my CPU on windows using a batch script.

on Ubuntu we can get it using below command and parse it for required string `sse4_2` or `sse4_1`.

```
RESP=$(head /proc/cpuinfo -n30)
```

Comment: This is unlikely going to be possible with a simple batch program but http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-cpuid-to-detect-the-presence-of-sse-41-and-sse-42-instruction-sets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121792/how-to-check-if-a-cpu-supports-the-sse3-instruction-set might be useful. The example code will compile by using the GCC compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think even WMI exposes this particular bit of information, otherwise what you want could have probably been accomplished using PowerShell (which could have been invoked from a batch file). I guess using third-party programs written using C/Assembly etc. is the only possible solution.

I recommend [CHKCPU (CPU Identification Utility)](http://web.inter.nl.net/hcc/J.Steunebrink/chkcpu.htm). Invoke it using `chkcpu32 /v` and you'll see output similar to the following:

[image: 1]
If you want, in your batch file you can pipe the output of the program to find/findstr and check which SSE version string is included.